# Change field data of other class in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have been developing module for Odoo8 under Ubuntu 14.04 . I am trying to set field data of my current class to field data of other class. I tried to assign the value but it does not get shown on the field of that other class. On printing the value on command prompt, it displays the right value but on Odoo field the textbox remains empty. Any clue or suggestions on this? Hopes for suggestion. Please check my code below

```
class hrEmployee(models.Model):

    _inherit = "hr.employee"



    passports_ids =  fields.One2many('hr.employee.passports', 'employee_id', 'Passport')          

class hr_employee_passports(models.Model):  
    _name='hr.employee.passports'    
    employee_id = fields.Many2one("hr.employee", "Employee" , ondelete="cascade")


    @api.onchange('passports_number')    
    @api.depends( 'passports_number')    
    def set_passport(self):
        result={} 

        if self.passports_number:

           for obj in self.employee_id:    
               obj.passport_id=self.passports_number
               print obj.passport_id  # this is the inherited field        

   passports_number = fields.Char('Passport No', help='Passport Number')
```

Comment: I guess you're looking for a computed field, but you should show us your code, this way we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: but I think, computed field will not work outside its own class

Comment: To copy a value from other model, a related field sounds the best option.

Comment: how may I use related field here

Answer (score -1):

class hrEmployee (models.Model):

```
_inherit = "hr.employee"



passports_ids =  fields.One2many('hr.employee.passports', 'employee_id', 'Passport')          

class hr_employee_passports(models.Model):  
_name='hr.employee.passports'    
employee_id = fields.Many2one("hr.employee", "Employee" ,   ondelete="cascade")

@api.one
@api.onchange('passports_number')        
def set_passport(self):
    result={} 

    if self.passports_number:

       for obj in self.employee_id:    
           obj.passport_id=self.passports_number

    return res{}
 passports_number = fields.Char('Passport No', help='Passport Number')
```